# How to change CATextLayer string throughout the video composition?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

- I want to create a video in which i want to change the text of CATextLayer with every second of video and create a new composition.

Answer (score 0):

You can add animation of text change on your `CATextLayer` and use `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` for export

[here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos) is an example how to use `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool`